# NodeJS version number confusion

Tags: node.js

I installed Node JS several months ago and played around a bit. Today, I wanted to start learning more about node and before coding, I decided I wanted to make sure I had the latest version.

I checked the version and it was something like v0.10.3x. I looked on the NodeJS website and it shows the latest version as v4.1.0. So I thought Woahhh! I better upgrade and I couldn't believe it moved that fast to a 4.x version in only a few months.

I spent quite some time trying to figure out how to completely uninstall node and npm because I couldn't seem to upgrade it.

Finally I got it all ripped out, then installed in on CentOS 7 using yum. I know I won't get the latest version through yum but, I figured it would be close enough.

After install, I am at v0.10.40.

I have a feeling I just don't understand something about NodeJS version numbers.

Comment: Appreciate the confusion, here is a link to the nodejs release types information - https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-types

Comment: "I spent quite some time trying to figure out how to completely uninstall node and npm because I couldn't seem to upgrade it." - please take a look at nvm - https://github.com/creationix/nvm  this makes installing, changing, and uninstalling versions of node and npm much easier.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Yeah if you only used the official node.js runtime then it would have appeared to jump from 0.12.x all the way to 4.0.0 in one fell swoop. What you may not have known was that node devs that were sick of how much the node repository was stagnating made a fork of the project and called it io.js. Under the io.js name the project marched forward over the last six months or so; it started at v1.x and iterated all the way through 2.x and 3.x in that time. Old node.js used a different versioning system wherein the odd versions were unstable and even versions were stable. Io.js switched to using [semver](http://semver.org/) versioning semantics like packages on npm already use.

After a lot of deliberation Joyent (original maintainers of node.js) finally caved in and helped form a proper open committee around node in an effort to push the project forward in much the same way io.js was already doing. A few months ago they agreed to merge io.js back into node.js (which was the goal of those who created io.js in the first place). They finally finished merging the two projects recently. The name io.js is no more and node.js lives on starting at v4.0. It will continue to use semver semantics like io.js did :)

Going forward things with node will be MUCH simpler. I'm excited to see where the project goes from here.

Comment: Thanks! I was aware of what happened with io.js as they started the fork, but not being an active node developer, was confused by the version schism when trying to figure out what I was using vs. what was available.

Comment: But why is there still development in v0.12.* (I see v0.12.14 release on May 6, 2016). Is this for backward compatibility?

Comment: @user276648 because 0.12 is an LTS (Long Term Support) version and they will continue to release important patches like security fixes, etc. You'll only ever see the patch number increase. 0.12.x

Comment: Here's the LTS info if anyone is interested. github.com/nodejs/LTS

Comment: Maybe you could call it a disaster before but releases are pretty regular now and the new LTS structure has been nice for peace of mind. Everything works very similar to Ubuntu releases now (just faster moving) and I'm pretty happy with it. Semver makes the most sense for node.

Comment: `io.js` is merged back into `Node.js` and there will be no further updates of `io.js`

Comment: I am wondering, why `node js` has this many different versions and update this fast, from 4 -------> 11 in 3 years (2015 to 2018), comparing to python (3.5.0 to 3.7.1) in 3 years (2015 to 2018)

Comment: Is Python following Semver?

Answer (score 4):

That is because since v4.0, the Node.js project and the io.js project that are now combined.
As for the io.js project, the version numbers were like v3.x, v2.x and v1.x.

Reference https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/

Comment: Very poor explanation. It assumes OP knows the io/node situation and adds to rather than clear any confusion for a newbie.

Answer (score 3):

You can use NVM(Node Versioning manager) for avoiding confusion.
Benefit of this package is you can switch b/w two versions according to your convenient. Its a very easy to use tool.

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-for-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Answer (score 2):

if you use npm you can upgrade with

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

once done try `node -v` to see what you got

see more at http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs

Comment: He wasn't asking how to upgrade, he was asking about the 0.x series of version numbers VS the 4.x series of version numbers.

Comment: Definitely not the answer of the OP's question, but just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can update node or npm using command line. You need to have a version of node or npm installed in your machine.
Use the following command in you terminal.

```
npm install node -g
npm install npm
```

You can also install the specific version of node, Like this.

```
npm install node@8.1.3 
npm install npm@4.1.2
```

Here 8.1.3 is a version number. Use any of the version you want to install.