# Where and how can I get a certain version of NodeJs?

Tags: node.js

I'll be attending a MS course tomorrow and I'm supposed to install NodeJs version 0.12.7. However, when I follow the [link provided](https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/), I only get a directory listing of a bunch of files. And I'm certainly not sure which one(s) I need (I'm on Win 8).

I also tried with their front page but the versions advertised there are v.4.2.2 and v.5.0.0, which surprised me (cf. v.0.12.7). When I went to the [downloads' section](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), I got totally confused by the overwhelming number of options, platforms, versions etc.

I trust my godlike ability to pick just the wrong option as well as my superpower of confusing everything to the edge of ridiculousness, so instead of cursing my rectum off, I prefer to ask straight how to obtain the requested version (v.0.12.7 for Win 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running 32-bit Windows, then you want the [`node-v0.12.7-x86.msi`](https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7-x86.msi) file in the directory in your link.

If you're running 64-bit Windows, then you want the [`node-v0.12.7-x64.msi`](https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/x64/node-v0.12.7-x64.msi) file in the `x64` subdirectory.

Comment: Right, thanks. It surprises me that there's such a vast version difference between the two advertised on the front page (v.4 and v.5) and the one requested (v.0). Is there any particular reason for that? Is the oldie (v.0.12) some kind of "mother core from before" or is it just an arbitrary version they happen to use? Is it likely that **any** version would do (and that the key speaker just wants to ensure that everything works **precisely** according to the plan)?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Node v4.0.0 was the first release after v0.12.7, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707088/nodejs-version-number-confusion) for more details on the curious version numbering. The newer versions should also work fine, but as you say, the speaker likely wants to keep things simple.

Comment: Ah, the eluding numbering system know as natural numbers... Instead of 1, 2, 3, 4 etc... Windows: 3, 95, 2000, 7, 8, 8.1, 10. NodeJs: 0.12, 4, 5... Full simplicity and not confusing at all... The same with movies - Terminator: 1, 2, 3 but then a bunch of sub-titles... Me not like! +1 for clarity for you, though. Are the NVM and  NodeEnv just different names for 4.2 and 5.0?

Comment: @KonradViltersten No, those are node version managers that let you easily switch between which version of Node.js you're using.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest nvm, it's great for node version management and installing any particular version of node you would like. https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Not sure how it relates to my question. At this stage I'm just trying to get the setup they're recommending for the sessions tomorrow (which is NodeJs v.0.12.7 and Visual Studio Code).

Comment: This is definitely the best answer despite the fact that OP doesn't understand that it's best.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ryan McDermott suggested, nvm is good. Another option, which I like, is nodenv: https://github.com/OiNutter/nodenv.

First, install `nodenv`. Then, install the plugin `node-build` (https://github.com/OiNutter/node-build). Then you can do the following:

```
nodenv install --list   # list available node versions
nodenv install 0.12.7   # install the specified version
nodenv global 0.12.7    # use the specified version of node
```