# How to understand the difference of edition in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I don't understand why Node.js has different editions. For instance, there is a 0.10.42 and a 4.4.3 edition.
What is different between the two?

Comment: sorry! The last word in the title is nodejs

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32707329/5812121). It's the answer in the above link and it should answer your question.